# Wordpress set image next new post title

Tags: php, wordpress

I have code:

```
    <div id="content88">
<div class="tip">
<div style="margin-left: 9%; margin-top: -2px;">
<center><h1><font style="margin-left:-50px;" font-size="20px" color="#BCBDC1">Last 5 posts from category</font></h1></center></p>
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=11446&posts_per_page=5' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>

<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><font color="#fff"><?php the_title(); ?></font></a> - <b>Last update:</b>  <span class="entry-date"><?php echo the_modified_time('Y/m/d \a\t g:i A'); ?></span> </h4> </p>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<center><h4><a href="#"><font style="margin-left:-50px;" font-size="14px" color="#BCBDC1">Click here for more results</font></a></h4></center></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This code lists last 5 posts from specific category. It looks like that:

[image: Click to view image]

It also delivers the time when the specific post was posted as you can see from the image above. What i want to do is have image next to posts which is x hours/days old that it would look like this:

[image: Click to view image]

But i fail to think proper way to do it even from what i should start, also i failed to find anything near what i need, maybe somebody could give me even example from what i should start? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply compare the timestamps of your post with the time you need:

```
<?php
    $olderThanTime = strtotime('-2 hours');
    $postTime      = strtotime(get_the_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', get_the_ID()));

    if ($postTime > $olderThanTime ) {
        the_post_thumbnail('small');
    }
?>
```